# Dealing with an encoding for Cyrillic

Tags: javascript, text, character-encoding, cyrillic

I'm not sure about how to deal with this encoding. I got the 5k most common russian words in this file with data that looks like this:

```
1 36358.94 Ë misc
2 27792.36 ‚ prep
3 20689.51 ÌÂ misc
4 18942.62 ÓÌ pron
5 16588.14 Ì‡ prep
6 15631.11 ˇ pron
7 12546.08 ˜ÚÓ misc...
```

I know that the 3rd word in each line is the cyrillic, however, I don't know how to turn those characters into the Cyrillic alphabet. If anyone could help, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **windows-1251** encoding, it should help.

Comment: Thanks! That would probably work, but I ended up getting a different database.